# Add two String numbers in Ocaml

Tags: string, numbers, ocaml, type-conversion

I’m doing my first steps on Ocaml and I want to write a function which will receive two numbers in String variables and will return the sum of the two received numbers in an string.

I know I could do the following

```
let sum a b =
  match a,b with
  | "1", "1" -> "2"
  | "1", "1.0" -> "2.0"
;;
```

I am aware it is infeasible for real life, so I would like to avoid the huge amount of cases I'll have to add. I'm also aware that I could use float_of_string and int_of_string for reducing the number of test cases.

Could you please give me some hints about how I should proceed?

Thanks in advance.
  ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, a more correct way would be to convert strings to numbers, and the apply operations, and afterwards inject the values back into the string, e.g,

```
let sum x y = string_of_int (int_of_string x + int_of_string y)
```

If you want to perform your arithmetic operations in the field of real numbers you can define your `sum` as:

```
let sum x y = string_of_float (float_of_string x + float_of_string y)
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, how should I manage the case when x is integer and y is float or the other way about?

Comment: `float_of_string` will read integer literals as floats, e.g. `float_of_string "1"` will be read as `1.0`, so the second `sum` example, will work for all cases. And it is natural, since integers are subset of reals.